# Port of discord.js bot/application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, ngrok

I think the answer is pretty simple, but for some reason I can't figure it out. I recently created a discord bot following the official discord docs (build on top of expressJS). That worked out without problems. Now, I wanted to switch to the discord.js library, but I can't figure out on what port the application is running. The old bot was running on port 3000, so I used ngrok for port forwarding.

On what port are discord.js apps running and how can I change that port?

Answer (score 0):

My bot works now, because I deleted the "INTERACTIONS ENDPOINT URL" in the Developer Portal. I looks like you don't need this URL, if you use discord.js instead of the express-based bot described in the official discord dev portal. Therefore port forwarding is no longer necessary.

If someone know the reason for that, please let me know.